# IConfiguration.GetSection always return null

Tags: wpf, unity-game-engine, .net-core, appsettings

I use Prism in my WPF application.

```
 protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>(new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build());
    }
```

this is what in my appsettings.json

```
{"User": {"Name": "ABC", "Age": 10  }}
```

in my viewmodel I want to get the User section like this

```
var Configuration = Container.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
var user = Configuration.GetSection("User");
```

however the value of user is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Configuration.GetSection("User")` should give you a `ConfigurationSection` and `Configuration["User:Name"]` and `Configuration["User:Age"]` should give you the values.

But why do you set the `optional` parameter to `false` when you call `AddJsonFile`? You should set it to `true` to get an exception if the `appsettings.json` file is not found in the output directory.

Make sure that you have set its `Build Action` to `Content` and its `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy if newer` in Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi mm8, thanks for your reply. if I use `Configuration["User:Name"]` or `Configuration["User:Age"]` i can get the values of Name and Age, but I want to get an instance of User, I defined a User Class `public class User
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }` but i don't know how to associate this User class to the configuration section

Comment: I did some research about the source code of `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider`, seems I cannot get the instance of User(in my case), I can only use `Configuration["User:Name"]` to get the plain value.